# Get current image data Flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

Is it possible to extract data from the current Flexslider image, like image ID, URL and name? I need to print the current image URL outside the flexslider div.

The code I'm using now:

```
jQuery('#slider').flexslider({
 animation: "fade",
 animationSpeed: 0,
 controlNav: false,
 animationLoop: false,
 smoothHeight: true,
 slideshow: false,
 keyboard: true,
 touch: true,
 directionNav: true
});
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `after` trigger which triggers after the slide changes:

```
jQuery('#slider').flexslider({
 after: function { // Code that fetches the needed data goes here },
 animation: "fade",
 animationSpeed: 0,
 controlNav: false,
 animationLoop: false,
 smoothHeight: true,
 slideshow: false,
 keyboard: true,
 touch: true,
 directionNav: true
});
```

A functioning demo is found here: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CPpBD/520/)

Comment: Many thanks for your effort and time Sari Alalem. Appreciate this.

Is it also possible to use the variable "url" outside jQuery?
I want to use this variable inside a Wordpress shortcode.

Comment: I'm not really that familiar with wordpress shortcodes, but they are processed on the server side, unlike Javascript/jQuery which is processed on the browse, what are you trying to acomplish?

Comment: To be more specific: I want to echo the image url into the following code:
 <a href="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.open({type: 'iframe', href : '/more-info/?data=urlImage">More info</a>